# How to bcc any email that is sent to an email address outside of my domain?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am looking to bcc any email that is sent to an email address outside of my domain.

I found this script that applies to all emails.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim objMe As Recipient
    Set objMe = Item.Recipients.Add("youremailaddress@whatever.com")
    objMe.Type = olBCC
    objMe.Resolve
    Set objMe = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: These posts show how to retrieve a domain and how to compare to your own to determine if external. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50629089/vba-script-if-elseif-check-if-external-and-internal and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58457310/flag-email-going-to-multiple-different-external-domains-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the BCC address added if an email is sent outside of your Exchange org, not just based on the domain name, right? Try something like the following (off the top of my head). The script checks if there are recipients other than EX type (meaning they are outside of your Exchange org):

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objMe As Recipient
    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    for each objRecip in Item.Recipients
      if objRecip.AddressEntry.Type <> "EX" Then
        Set objMe = Item.Recipients.Add("youremailaddress@whatever.com")
        objMe.Type = olBCC
        objMe.Resolve
        Set objMe = Nothing
        exit for
      End If
    next
End Sub
```